# can't create eks cluster due to ARN sts get-caller identity issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

The command i tried:

```
eksctl create cluster --name dev --version 1.21 --region us-east-1 

--zones us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c,us-east-1d,
us-east-1f --nodegroup-name standard-workers --node-type t3.micro 

--nodes 3 --nodes-min 1 --nodes-max 4 --managed
```

But it gives this error:

```
Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode:
 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post "https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": net/http: invalid header field value "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credenti
al=\x1b[2~/20220612/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, S
ignature=4e5bb539c064ce728f4979be3f5f082bc8eaf8e8f68b22c17898929997fc479d" for key Authorization
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-30 ~]$
```

But the IAM seems to be fine, i even added all existing EKS policies i could find.

[image: kk]

Administrator access policy also has EKS full access,what's wrong?

Running 'aws sts get-caller-identity' gives this error response:

```
> aws sts get-caller-identity 
> Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), 
> invalid XML received. 
> Further retries may succeed: b''
```

Comment: did you figure out the issue?